# Please help me identify this weed and what herbicide I can use to get rid of it in St. Augustine Grass

Tags: identification, lawn, weed-control, grass

I have this weed taking over a spot in my St. Augustine grass. What is it and how should I get rid of it. Warm climate in South Florida.

[image: photo of unknown weed]

It seems to have small blueish flowers and the roots are really able to choke competition. Looking to do some post emergent too. Don't want it coming back.

Thanks

Edit:

Here it is in the ground.

[image: photo of unknown weed in the ground]

Another better view:

[image: another photo of unknown weed]

Comment: Can you give us a picture of the weed as it is growing, and also reverse the orientation of the existing image?

Comment: I wonder if it's one of the Tradescantia

Comment: I am thinking Veronica or Speedwell.  Which thrives with low mowing heights.

Comment: Added another close up view. @stormy. If you write up an answer with some herbicide recommendations to be used in St. Augustine turf grass I can mark it accepted.

Comment: OK...wandering jew...Graham?

Comment: How much of your lawn has this spiderwort?  Is it just in the shade?  Brenn has an excellent article and I'll send this along as well.  You've got a tough weed for sure.  Read this and Brenn's article and let us know if we are close.  Glyphosate will kill your grass as well.  From what little I know this weed is very glyphosate resistant, it has a thick, glossy epidermis.

Comment: https://sites.google.com/site/palmgroveourimbahcreeklandcare/home/controlling-environmental-weeds/controlling-tradescantia

Comment: Yeah it's nasty stuff. Really can't pull it very well either and from what I read you gotta get it all. Chances you can break this down in layman terms? Link does not work on phone and don't have a ton of time to research. Thanks for all the help so far.

Comment: This weed loves lots of water and can out compete healthy turf in the shade.  I'd quit paddling upstream and resize, re-define the lawn edges and not grow lawn where it will always have trouble competing with this.  I love crushed gravel, 3/8 minus.  Put an edger pt 2X4 scored to bend between lawn and the informal graveled park/patio.  No herbicide will eradicate this problem.  Best to just  'go with the flow' or 'choose your battles'...cutting out the portions of your lawn with this weed will be easier than hoping some chemical will make it all work.  Check this out on your home computer...

Comment: Is this weed primarily in the parts of your lawn that has shade?  Do you water every day?  What herbicides have you tried?  Give more information as much as you are able.  One thing about lawns is that the eye sees the edges not the bulk.  Crisp, well defined edges and shape, curves with set radius until changing direction then another set radius looks beautiful.  You will always have this weed in your lawn.  To try to eradicate would mean complete kill of your lawn and re planting and still you would have this weed.  What are your neighbors doing?

Comment: It seems to be growing where an oak tree provides partial shade throughout the day. It's also a spot that the irrigation system gets more wet than the rest. Going to pull these by hand as I see them and try to reduce the water in the area. Might even try to cut back the oak tree. Would really like to figure out some kind of herbicide that would be some help too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's Commelina diffusa (aka communis). Some advice for control: [PDF](https://www.ars.usda.gov/ARSUserFiles/60663500/Publications/Hoagland/2015/Boyette%20et%20al._2015_Agronomy_5-519-536.pdf)

And here: [Asiatic Dayflower The Little Beauty that Caused So Much Confliction](http://hyg.ipm.illinois.edu/article.php?id=507)

Wikipedia: Commelina diffusa, sometimes known as the climbing dayflower or spreading dayflower, is a pantropical herbaceous plant in the dayflower family. It has been introduced to the southeastern United States where it is most common in wet disturbed soils. There are two recognised varieties, one being the type and the other being C. diffusa var. gigas, which is native to Asia and has been introduced to Florida. It flowers from spring to fall and is most common in disturbed situations, moist places and forests. In China the plant is used medicinally as a febrifuge and a diuretic. A blue dye is also extracted from the flower for paints. In the Hawaiian Islands, it is known as "honohono grass", although it is technically not a grass. "Honohono" refers to the alternating structure of the leaves. At least one publication lists it as an edible plant in New Guinea.

[Full Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commelina_diffusa)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a synopsis for the link you offered for quick reference?

Comment: Sure. See edit.

Comment: If you're referring to the article about eradication, the PDF, it's best to download it. It's lengthy,

Comment: I attempted to post the contents of the PDF as a comment but the justification was all over the place. Try the PDF, most newer mobiles should be able to parse it.